# Show that $E(E(Y|X)=E(Y)$

Tags: conditional-expectation

$X,Y$ discrete, integrable Random variables on $(\Omega,A,P)$.

> > Show that $E(E(Y|X))=E(Y)$.

First of all in another task it was to show that $E(Y|X)$ is a discrete Random variable. So it is
$$
E(E(Y|X))=\sum_{z}zP(E(Y|X)=z),
$$
Moreover it is
$$
E(Y|X)(\omega):=\sum_x E(Y|X=x)1_{X=x}(\omega)
$$
and
$$
E(Y|X=x):=\sum_y y P(Y=y|X=x).
$$

So putting this all together I get 
$$
E(E(Y|X))=\sum_z zP\left(\sum_x\sum_y yP(Y=y|X=x)1_{X=x}=z\right)
$$

Oh my god. What can I do now to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general thing to remember is not to introduce $\omega$ unless you absolutely have to.

Just stay with
$$
E(Y|X=x)=\sum_y y P(Y=y|X=x).
$$
Use 
$$
P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x) = {P(Y=y,X=x)}$$
Now remember that $E(Y|X)$ is a function of $X(\omega)$, so
$$
E[E(Y|X)] = \sum P(X=x) E(Y|X=x)
$$
and you will be fine.

Comment: Isn't $E(Y|X)$ a function of $\omega$ and not of $x$?

Comment: Sorry (again) I do not understand you.

Comment: actually it is a function of $X(\omega)$.It does not depend on $\omega$ in any other way.

Comment: no this time it is an error from me ;)

Comment: I do understand the first line and the second line. But not why $E(Y|X)$ is a function of $X(\omega)$ because in the task it is defined $E(Y|X)(\omega):=...$ so it is a function of $\omega$. And even if it is indeed a function of $X(\omega)$ then I cannot see how you get the last formula and why this is $E(Y)$.

Comment: this is a function of $\omega$, of course: this is a random variable. But it does depend on $\omega$ only through $X(\omega)$: this is a deterministic function of $X(\omega)$. That is why the 3rd line.

Comment: I see now, thank you. Noe the remaining question is why the 3rd line is equal to E(Y). I thought og total probability but cannot finish it

Comment: Ok, I found it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation Did not know this formula before.

Comment: So maybe it would be better to define it like $E(Y|X(\omega)):=...$ instead of $E(Y|X)(\omega):=...$?

Comment: No, because it would mean that $E[Y|.]$ is a function, which does not make sense. Sometimes, this function is noted $E[Y|X = X(\omega)]$. But I don't like this one.

Comment: Hm do not see clearly yet... but ok. And is the sum in the third line over x or y? I think x. But then its different than in the lnk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17973/discussion-between-mathfemi-and-mookid).